# Xamarin.iOS, Info.plist - App Icon setting - is set back to None after Saving and reopening the file

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac, info.plist, appicon

I'm facing an issue in my Xamarin.Forms iOS project, and I'm hoping someone can help me to resolve it. (Visual Studio Mac, Xamarin forms)

Problem Summary:
In my Xamarin.Forms iOS project, I'm having trouble properly configuring the app icon. I imported all the different Icon sizes into my asset catalog and am also able to set my asset catalog in the info.plist file. But after I saved the file, exited and reopened it again the app icon setting is back at None.
I don't understand why.
(I also checked that all the image sources are correctly referenced in my xamarin.ios.csproj file which they do)

And because of all that, when archiving the project and uploading it to the App Store I get these 2 Error messages:
Asset validation failed (90022)
Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0. To support older versions of iOS, the icon may be required in the bundle outside of an asset catalog. Make sure the Info.plist file includes appropriate entries referencing the file. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface (ID: ece0da35-1040-4f11-879c-aa9993eb9626)

Asset validation failed (90713)
Missing Info.plist value. A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'com.companyname.PeulaCloud'. Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key. For more information see http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7. (ID: 69a54910-816d-4293-beab-19c6c6be55d6)

things I allready tried:

eleting the xcassets, created a new one and importing all the images again

Checking my Contents.json file for any missing references

Adding this to the info.plist file (in the editor):

CFBundleIconName
AppIcon

Comment: 1. May I know what is the version of your Visual Studio? 2.Please close your VS for mac, delete all of the bin and obj folders, and rebuild your project in the VS.

Comment: i solved the problem! weirdly I had a wrong Icon source inside of the info.plist that gave xamarin forms the whole path of the .xcassets folder but you don't need the whole path only the Path after ProjectName.iOS. Thanks anyway

Comment: No worries, glad to see you fix it. You can add more details to your comment and post it as an answer as it'll help others facing the same issue.